# How do I retrieve Angular module's declarations/imports/providers from a function with more that one instruction?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to split my `app.module.ts` in multiple files. To do this, I need to be able to retrieve declarations, imports and providers from a function.

This works but only if the function return a simple array with no other instruction. If I had more than one instructions in the function then the application fails to load.

For example lets start with a simple project :

```
ng new my-app
? Do you want to enforce stricter type checking and stricter bundle budgets in the workspace?
  This setting helps improve maintainability and catch bugs ahead of time.
  For more information, see https://angular.io/strict Yes
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? SCSS   [ https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax#scss ]

ng serve
```

Initial `app.module.ts` has following code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This works well.

Now if I move `declarations` array in a function `GetDeclarations()`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

function GetDeclarations() : (any[] | Type<any>)[] {
  return [
    AppComponent
  ]
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: GetDeclarations(),
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This also works.

Finally, if I add one single instruction that does nothing in `GetDeclarations()`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

function GetDeclarations() : (any[] | Type<any>)[] {
  let i = true;
  return [
    AppComponent
  ]
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: GetDeclarations(),
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then everything breaks.

This also breaks if I declare the array in a const and then return it. Everything must be done in one single instruction.

Here is the resulting error:

```
Build at: 2021-03-29T21:32:19.023Z - Hash: f5a6b698446c86ceeea0 - Time: 1296ms

Error: src/app/app.component.html:416:25 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngSwitch' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

416   <div class="terminal" [ngSwitch]="selection.value">
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:534:1 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

534 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:23:17 - error NG1010: Expected array when reading the NgModule.declarations of AppModule
  Value could not be determined statically.

23   declarations: GetDeclarations(),
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.module.ts:23:17
    23   declarations: GetDeclarations(),
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Unable to evaluate function call of complex function. A function must have exactly one return statement.
  src/app/app.module.ts:15:1
     15 function GetDeclarations() : (any[] | Type<any>)[] {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     16   let i = true;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ...
     19   ]
        ~~~
     20 }
        ~
    Function is declared here.
```

Do you have any idea of what is happening here?

Is there any way to retrieve those declarations, imports and providers from complex functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're somewhat limited in what you can express in the `@NgModule`-decorator, and function-expressions as to determining dependencies simply doesn't work.

May I suggest that instead of trying to split out the various declarations, imports and providers etc. you look into a modular approach to your application design?

Eg.:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: GetDeclarations(),
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    UserModule, // Contains declarations, imports, providers for user-functionality
    ProductModule, // Contains declarations, imports, providers for product-functionality
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The `UserModule`, and `ProductModule` is of course only examples.

This will also allow for you to do lazy loading at a "later point in point"

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer :)
Do you know what are the mechanisms behind this limitation? I can't find an explanation based on TS mechanisms? Is this related to webpack?

Splitting by modules seems not to answer my needs.
In our project we sometimes need to replace specific components for some of our clients. So I tried to create a GetDeclarations() method that can be "hooked" to replace some of the array's entries.
If not possible, I will try another solution using generated app.module.ts based on a template file so we don't interact with angular compilation.

Comment: No it's not at all related to limitations in webpack. It's just the way that the `@NgModule` system is designed. If you have specific needs for a certain customer, you could probably create shared components in a `SharedModule`, and then create a per customer module (eg. `CustomerOneModule`) that uses the SharedModule. Although, if changes are somewhat triviel, I'd probably make customizable Components that use settings from `environment.ts`, and create one file per customer (you get dev / prod out-of-the box).